# C# FormatException without any numeric or null value parsing involved

Tags: c#, string-formatting

This line is throwing a FormatException:

```
var dataString = string.Format("email_address:{0}, status:subscribed, merge_fields:{1}", "a", "b");
```

No doubt the problem is obvious, but I am not seeing it.

Here is the function:

```
   public static string AddSubscriber(string listId, Subscriber subscriber) {

            string url = string.Format("https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{0}/members/", listId);

            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", basicAuth);

            var mergeFieldJson = subscriber.MergeFields();
            var dataString = string.Format("email_address:{0}, status:subscribed, merge_fields:{1}", "a", "b"); // subscriber.email, mergeFieldJson);

            /*
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
            using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            */
            return "";
        }
```

Here is the exception:

```
Input string was not in a correct format. 
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
    at MailChimpLib.MailChimp.AddSubscriber(String listId, Subscriber subscriber) in d:\Development\GTPRepository\team24x7\trunk\MailChimpLib\MailChimp.cs:line 40
    at team24x7.Controllers.StoreController.AddTestSubscriber() in d:\Development\GTPRepository\team24x7\trunk\team24x7\api_source\Controllers\StoreController.cs:line 167
```

Line 40 is the line with the string.Format(..).

Here is the MergeFields function:

```
   public string MergeFields() {
        return string.Format("{'Email':'{0}','First Name':'{1}','Last Name':'{2}','Mascot':'{3}','Store Link':'{4}','School':'{5}'}",
            email, firstname, lastname, mascot, storelink, school
        );
    }
```

For me it works in debug mode, but causes an exception in the line following the call to it in release mode.

No doubt the problem is related to the silly and erroneous attempt to include the initial and ending curly brace in the format string. (Stupidity cursed.)

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Are you sure that the exception is on this line?

Comment: You are probably wrong on the fact that this throws an exception.

Comment: I edited the question and included the function and the traceback. Line 40 is the line with the string.Format(..). I would say that I'm voodoo cursed, but I'm probably just stupidity cursed.

Comment: Still not enough code. I suppose that the exception comes from `subscriber.MergeFields();`

Comment: You're right, that's is where the problem was. Why does the traceback say line 40? Why does it not even mention the the previous line or the MergeFields function at all? I moved that call out of that line and onto the previous line specifically to be able to tell whether or not the problem was in MergeFields(). Argh.

Comment: One reason about wrong stack trace can be the jitter - it tries to do some optimizations, reorder some istructions etc. This can happen if you run the code in release mode.

Comment: You're right again. I was running in release mode. I'd switched it, for some reason that I don't remember, and forgotten. When I switch to debug mode... the problem goes away entirely! I can comment the contents of MergeFields() back in, and it runs fine. I think actually that's why I was running in release mode - when I switch to release mode, I get problems that I don't get in debug mode.

Comment: @Shavais I posted an answer with description of the problem and suggested solution.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Man, it's so nice to be able to reach out to other developers on Stack Overflow and actually get helpful responses in a matter of minutes. It's a brave new world, these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few comments we came to the source of the problem:

```
return string.Format("{'Email':'{0}','First Name':'{1}','Last Name':'{2}','Mascot':'{3}','Store Link':'{4}','School':'{5}'}",
    email, firstname, lastname, mascot, storelink, school
);
```

Here you got `FormatException` because you have curly brace `{` symbol in your string which has a special meaning when formating strings. The solution is to escape it with double curly braces `{{` or `}}` so your code becomes:

```
return string.Format("{{'Email':'{0}','First Name':'{1}','Last Name':'{2}','Mascot':'{3}','Store Link':'{4}','School':'{5}'}}",
    email, firstname, lastname, mascot, storelink, school
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code in Ideone and it is working fine.

https://ideone.com/cHQC3O

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dataString = string.Format("email_address:{0}, status:subscribed, merge_fields:{1}", "a", "b");
        Console.WriteLine(dataString);
    }
}
```

It seems we are missing something not mentioned in code.

What exception are you getting? What is the message of exception?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was afraid that might be the case. The traceback is clearly identifying that line of code, but there must be something else going on.

Comment: Are `"a"` and `"b"` literally the values used for this line of code, or are they the [assumed] values of an object's properties?If the latter, perhaps they were not initialized or they are not strings.

Comment: I've edited the post the show the whole function and the exception. It's beyond bizarre. I would ask "why does this kind of thing happen to me", but usually when I ask that question I end up realizing that there is some mistake I've made.

Comment: @NikG: `String.Format` is an intelligent method. It can handle null values. Moreover if is not string `String.Format` internalls calls `ToString()` Which is available in all types because it is available in `Object` Class.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Oh, I didn't realize. I distinctly remember getting messages about that not being able to compile if there was a type mismatch, but now that I think about it, it was probably a Resharper error.